# Use cursor value to make combination dynamically and use it while inserting in a row

Tags: sql, oracle

I am pulling values in a cursor say from table called my_table and depending on the condition it may return a, b, c, d etc. Now with those values I need to prepare a combination of a, ab, ac, ad, b, bc,bd, c, cd and so on. I want to use these values while inserting a row in another 2 tables where in one table I will use the combination values together in a column and in another table I'll use original values separately used in the combination. The first table id will be the FK of the second table while inserting data. How to achieve the same.

Comment: Why not use a database trigger in `my_table` to populate values in `table1 `and `table2`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like as mentioned below, change the code as per your requirement.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_table_trg
   AFTER INSERT
   ON my_table
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   CURSOR comb_values
   IS
      SELECT .......;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN comb_values
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO table1
           VALUES (i.combination_values);

      INSERT INTO table2
           VALUES (i.non_combination_values);
   END LOOP;
END;
```